# Displaying number of instances of each array value

Tags: php, array-unique

```
$myArray = array(2, 7, 4, 2, 5, 7, 6, 7);

$uniques = array_unique($myArray);
```

Along with displaying each value in the array only once, how would I ALSO display (in the foreach loop below) the number of times each value is populated in the array. IE next to '7' (the array value), I need to display '3' (the number of times 7 is in the array)

```
foreach ($uniques as $values) {
echo $values . " " /* need to display number of instances of this value right here */ ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/array_count_values) function instead.

```
$myArray = array(2, 7, 4, 2, 5, 7, 6, 7);
$values = array_count_values($myArray);
foreach($values as $value => $count){
echo "$value ($count)<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`array_count_values`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php).

Quoting from the manual:

> **Example #1 array_count_values() example**
>
> ```
> <?php
> $array = array(1, "hello", 1, "world", "hello");
> print_r(array_count_values($array));
> ?>
> ```
>
> The above example will output:
>
> ```
> Array
> (
>     [1] => 2
>     [hello] => 2
>     [world] => 1
> )
> ```